# Running Ubuntu 22.04 on iMac 2019.1 Sonoma. Wireless + Bluetooth wouldn't start

Tags: networking, drivers, 22.04, bluetooth, mac

I have just installed Ubuntu 22.04 by following this [guide](https://gist.github.com/sebnyberg/ccf6b6c37df99a125bc2346977284622):

The installation went smoothly, but none of the connections worked (Bluetooth, WiFi, cable).
The `ioreg -l | grep RequestedFiles` output is the following:

```
"RequestedFiles" = ({"Firmware"="C-4364__s-B2/midway.trx",
"TxCap"="C-4364__s-B2/midway-X3.txcb",
"Regulatory"="C-4364__s-B2/midway-X3.clmb",
"NVRAM"="C-4364__s-B2/P-midway-X3_M-HRPN_V-m__m-7.7.txt"})
```

I copied these files and renamed them accordingly in my Ubuntu install `midway-X3.trx -> brcmfmac4364b2-pcie.bin,  midway-X3.trx -> brcmfmac4364b2-pcie.apple,midway.bin, midway-X3.clmb -> brcmfmac4364b2-pcie.clm_blob P-midway-X3_M-HRPN_V-m__m-7.7.txt -> brcmfmac4364b2-pcie.txt, midway-X3.txcb -> brcmfmac4364b2-pcie.txcap_blob`, but I'm still getting the error like that when running `journalctl -k --grep=brcmfmac`:

```
 [    4.005003] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    4.005050] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.116133] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac4364b2-pcie for chip BCM4364/3
[    4.119702] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4364b2-pcie.Apple Inc.-iMac19,1.bin failed with error -2
[    4.119876] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4364b2-pcie.bin failed with error -2
[    4.119879] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0: brcmf_pcie_setup: Dongle setup failed
[    4.119898] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_fw_crashed: Firmware has halted or crashed
[    4.429824] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM.hcd'
[  139.562534] usbcore: deregistering interface driver brcmfmac
```

is there something that I've missed? Can anyone point me in the correct direction to be able to solve this issue?

the output of `lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network`

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4364 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4464] (rev 03)
Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4364 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [106b:07bf]
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort+ <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
Region 0: Memory at 81400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
Region 2: Memory at 81000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel modules: brcmfmac
```

04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM57766 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1686] (rev 01)

UPD:
I was able to make the cable connection run by using the script from this guide (or maybe my provider started to recognize my cable connection, dunno): https://wiki.t2linux.org/guides/wifi-bluetooth/

Comment: Should've copied midway.trx instead of midway-x3.trx, wifi is working now.